Array Bounds Overrun inside of ML.NET - at my wits end
At my wits end...
T5.omnx - ML.Net implementation trying to get down into text summarization...
Have this text harness - guts of which are below - the harnes is simple proof of component usability...
I have tried a number of T5 models - all wind me to the same dead end road of type mismatching between encoder outputs and decoder inputs...
I have checked, double and triple that all arrays are shaped and populalted as expected...
I have used netron on the current model it reports:
INPUTS:             
                name: input_ids tensor: int64[1,128]
                name: attention_mask tensor: float32[1,128]
OUTPUTS:            
                name: input.103 tensor: float32[1,128,512]

I am using these data models...
 internal class CombinedInput
    {
        [ColumnName("input_ids")]
        public long[] InputIds { get; set; }

        [ColumnName("attention_mask")]
        public float[] AttentionMask { get; set; }
    }

    internal class CombinedOutput
    {
        [ColumnName("input.103")] // Ensure this matches your model's output name
        public VBuffer<float> Output { get; set; } // This should match the expected shape

        public CombinedOutput()
        {
            // Initialize the VBuffer with a default size (if you know the expected size)
            // For example, if you expect 512 outputs:
            Output = new VBuffer<float>(128, new float[128]);
        }
    }

The CombinedOutput constructor was due to non defined array during predict...
Here is my code....  which prints the results shown below...
Types of array match netron.org config report shown above...
Console.WriteLine("Experiment: Create and Exercise Combined T5 Model.");
             
    var tokenizer = new GCSTokenizer();   // simple long assignment to each word
    var inputIds = tokenizer.Tokenize(Assets.EAS_Message);

    var inputData = new CombinedInput()
    {
        InputIds = inputIds,
        AttentionMask = tokenizer.GetAttentionMask(inputIds)
    };

    // Logging for debugging
    Console.WriteLine($"Input IDs: {string.Join(", ", inputData.InputIds)}");
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
    Console.WriteLine($"Attention Mask: {string.Join(", ", inputData.AttentionMask)}");
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
    var model = GetCombinedModel();  // built using new CombinedInput[] { }
    var predictionEngine = Assets.mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<CombinedInput, CombinedOutput>(model);

    try
    {
        var result = predictionEngine.Predict(inputData);  //Out or range throws here ... .
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Prediction failed: {ex.Message}");
    }



************* run output *****************

Experiment: Create and Exercise Combined T5 Model.
Input IDs: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 4, 12, 13, 7, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 18, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 23, 32, 33, 34, 13, 35, 36, 37, 38, 13, 21, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 46, 34, 47, 13, 48, 49, 9, 50, 51, 52, 18, 53, 24, 54, 55, 56, 51, 34, 57, 13, 58, 59, 59, 55, 18, 60, 61, 62, 38, 63, 64, 33, 65, 66, 67, 18, 68, 69, 70, 71, 23, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 16, 91, 92, 29, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 23, 100, 101, 102
Attention Mask: 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
Prediction failed: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')
Press Any Key!
PS: the raw tokenId list is 488 elements long - using control data set - this is truncated to the 128 - while not IDEAL - this experiment is to determine if we can use ML.net in our use case... we will handle the sliding inputs later (if there is reason)
SO any pointers on why I cannot predict with this data and these models... Thanks in advance..
Please refer to the above for current codebase and steps preformed thus far

Found my own answer -> thanks to everyone!
